# replacement for tabbar selected index

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, selectedindex

I have an old app where I have 5 tabs. Each tab have list of ads & there is details. Also each tab have respective add ad. Design for all 5 tabs is same except some changes, so I decided to use 1 screen only for all 5 tabs.

Now what I am doing is while add ad, I am checking which tab I am and based on tab bar index, I am showing hiding fields. Same is applicable for details screen also. Sample code is as shown below.

```
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==0) {
    field1.hidden = NO;
} else if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==1) {
    field1.hidden = NO;
} else if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {
    field1.hidden = NO;
} else if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==3) {
    field1.hidden = NO;
} else if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==4) {
    field1.hidden = YES;
}
```

Now I have around 15 fields for each form so I write this code for all fields.

What I noticed that client change the tab bar position continuously so I was looking for efficient way of doing it.

Right now what I do is at all places manually change index positions by doing Search-Replace, however I dont like this.

I was looking for a way where instead of selectedIndex, I was looking for someconstant value that I will assign to tab item of tab bar, so my code will change as below

```
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==adType_News) {
    field1.hidden = NO;
} else if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==adType_Occasions) {
.
.
And so on...
```

This way, I only need to change in the storyboard and code level will not have any changes.

Is there way where I can achieve this?

### Main Issue

As client ask to change tab bar completely, I need to make changes of selectedIndex changes at all places which I don't like and feel more in-efficient way. So I was looking for a way where I will make change in storyboard only and coding level there won't be any change.

The main issue for me is changing selectedIndex in all files which make more error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand the question to mean that the code is full of number literals, referring to the selected index of the tabbar, and the business requirements about the ordering of items are shifting.  Fix by changing the literals to something symbolic that can be controlled centrally:

```
// in a new file, indexes.h
#define INDEXA  (0)
#define INDEXB  (1)
#define INDEXC  (2)

// wherever existing code refers to the tab selection
#import "indexes.h"

// in the code, for example if selectedIndex == 2, change to
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==INDEXC) {
    // ...
```

Comment: but when I change in storyboard earlier items[0] is items[2] now (considering client say I want to exchange 3rd with 1st)

Comment: can you explain change items?  do you mean at design time, or the items can be rearranged while the app is running?

Comment: I am fine doing run-time also. The main concern for me is doing replacement in all files... as this is old app I was preferring to change in storyboard and not to touch programming...

Comment: consider client say that he want to flip first and last tab bar... I want to do by very less coding...

Comment: oh - why not  `#define INDEX_OF_ITEMA  (0)` 1,2,3... for every index.  Replace all of the number literals in your code with INDEX_OF...  When the client changes his mind about order, just change the #defines.  It's one code touch.

Comment: in prefix, right? but tab bar controller won't be accessible there

Comment: not sure what you mean.  you'd make a new header file, myindexes.h, fill it with #defines, import it into each vc that refers to the selected index.

Comment: ahh, will try tomorrow and let you know... can you post this in answer so that I can accept...

Comment: didn't realize the question was about code maintenance.